# compute idf in python using nltk

Tags: python

I was trying to compute inverse document frequencies using `nltk` as follow:

```
#get a sorted dictionary of frequencies of each unique words.
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(concatAllString)
fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(words)
all_words_dict = dict((word, freq) for word, freq in fdist1.items() if not word.isdigit())
all_words_dict=dict(sorted(all_words_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))



#Step4: Filter out all stop words from the dictionary and words of length greater than 6 and less than 2
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
all_words_dict={k:v for k, v in all_words_dict.items() if k not in stop_words and len(k)<=6 and len(k)>1}


#Step5: get 1000 feature words with highest frequencies from the all_words_dictionary
feature_words =  dict(itertools.islice(all_words_dict.items(), 1000))
```

newline

```
from nltk.text import TextCollection
mytexts = TextCollection(preposed_originalTrain)

idfTable=[0]*len(feature_words)
for j in range(len(feature_words)):
    idfTable[j]=mytexts.idf(feature_words[j])

print(idfTable)
```

Here `presosed_words` is a list of strings where each element in the string is a message. Also `feature_words` is a list of predefined words. but I get `keyerror 0` I don't understand why?

**Update:** I changed the code to this:

```
    idfTable=[0]*len(feature_words)
    tempIndex=0
    for key, value in feature_words.items(): 
        idftable[tempIndex] = mytexts.idf(value)
        tempIndex=tempIndex+1
```

I get this error instead:
[image]

Comment: where you have initialized feature_words? Can you paste sample data (feature_words)?

Comment: try `for key, value in feature_words.iteritems():` and then `idftable[key] = mytexts.idf(value)`

Comment: It still not working

Comment: I forgot to mention. Before the for loop, have `idftable = dict()`. Basically, idftable should be a dictionary. with `[0]*len(feature_words)`, it becomes a list.